# css form validation jquery

Tags: jquery, css, forms, validation

I have a script and I want the "message" error to display text in my input box.
The input form's ID is "email", but it seems I can't change this format to allow anything other than text and not change the input of the form?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "oh man!",

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('.EmailList').html(data);

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

THE FORM:

```
form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
    <div class="Email">                     
        <label for="Email"></label>
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="76%"><label for="Email"></label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="daEmail" size="30" value=""/> </td>
            <td width="24%"><input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/Submit.png" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where is .EmailList class in html?

Comment: I would generally advise against the message being in or over the input field, as you'll replace/cover up the original user input. I'd place the message below or next to the field, or in a bubble http://girliemac.com/blog/2011/11/28/html5-form-field-validation-with-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Your input box id is "daEmail" so you have to use that name in jquery,

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('#daEmail').val(data);
```

**html code**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="daEmail" size="30" value=""/>
```